# Does velocity of a collision affect time of the collision?

Tags: collision

If two objects collide, increasing velocity before the collision should not change the distance they travel before coming to rest, but would it affect the time it takes for them to come to rest?

Comment: Not sure why changing velocitiy will not change the distance before they come to rest.

Comment: Please clarify: are you asking about elastic or inelastic collision? What is the mechanism that leads to the objects "coming to rest"? Are you asking this in the center of mass frame of reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not easy to understand what you are asking, so let me try to describe my understanding of your question. Let us consider two objects of equal mass moving towards each other along axis $x$ with velocities $v$ and $-v$, and their center of mass is always at point $x=0$. After the collision they come to rest, either permanently, if the collision is completely inelastic, or just for a moment, if the collision is perfectly elastic. The distance the objects travel until they come to rest does not depend (much) on the velocity (the objects cannot move beyond point $x=0$). Does "the time it takes for them to come to rest" depend on the velocity? Hertz solved this problem for a perfectly elastic collision of two balls, and the time does depend on the velocity, but rather weakly (as $v^{-\frac{1}{5}}$) (http://www.physics.emory.edu/faculty/brody/Advanced%20Lab/Advanced-Lab-Elasticity3.pdf).